# Incorporate setText and setNum into a label in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a few very simple lines of code of the slot for a horizontal slider:

```
void newwindow::on_horizontalSlider_valueChanged(int value)
{
    ui->label->setNum(value);
}
```

Now, instead of the label just displaying a number (such as "11" or "42"), how would I make it display "Value: 11"?

I think that I would probably have to incorporate setText into this too, although I don't know how I would do that.

There's probably a really simple solution but I haven't found it yet. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `QString::number` to convert int to `QString` :

```
 ui->label->setText(QString("Value: ") + QString::number(value));
```

Comment: Much better than the solution I found a few seconds ago. One question somewhat related, I'm sort of new to Qt, how do you know when something is a QString as opposed to just a normal string? I guess this question also applies for other things that start with a "Q" as opposed to its "non-Q" counterpart.

Comment: @AdminVoter With QString("Value: ") I told to compiler that it is QString, so it will be properly processed anywhere. There are many different answers about STL and Qt STL, use std::string or QString,  QVector or std::vector. I think that if you work with normal Qt project, you need to use Qt classes, but when you use third-party libraries you should use standard. For example, powerful library of computer vision OpenCV works only with string and vector and so on, so I can't use Qt classes, but don't forget that Qt provide special methods to convert (such as toStdString, toStdVector and so on)

Comment: @RaydelMiranda Yup, I was just waiting for the countdown to disable :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`QString::arg`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstring.html#arg) to add arguments to your string:

```
void newwindow::on_horizontalSlider_valueChanged(int value)
{
    ui->label->setText(QString("Value: %1").arg(value));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wow, I didn't think of just adding the setText afterwards:

```
void newwindow::on_horizontalSlider_valueChanged(int value)
{
    ui->label->setNum(value);
    ui->label->setText("Value: " + ui->label->text());
}
```

What is simply does is, it sets the text of the label to, say, "15" and then concatenates the word "Value: " right after it. It was a simple solution, although if someone has an even simpler one, feel free to add it :P

Comment: This is quite a roundabout way of coding this. It does not express your intent well.

Comment: I know what you mean, but I'm genuinely wondering, why isn't it a good way to write the code (besides the fact that it is a whole line of code more)?

Comment: It modifies the label twice, while there is nothing preventing you from doing it only once. Additionally, you're hiding the fact that you actually convert the `int` to a string here, although that may be debatable. In essence: you're misusing the `setNum` convenience function as an `int`-to-string conversion function, because you're modifying it directly afterwards by resusing the result itself.